# Функция free() не освобождает память

Tags: c

Подскажите, у меня есть вот такая функция в которой используется free():

```
void removeNode(struct Node** t) {
    int key;
    struct Node ** rm;
    struct Node *replace;
    puts("Vvedite iskomiy key");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    (*rm) = searchKey(*t, key);
    if (rm == NULL) {
        puts("not found");
        return;
    }
    if ((*rm)->llink == 1 && (*rm)->llink == 1) {
        if ((*rm)->p->r == (*rm)) {
            (*rm)->p->r = (*rm)->p->p;
            (*rm)->p->rlink=1;
        }
        else {
            (*rm)->p->l = getLLink((*rm)->p->key, (*rm)->p);
             (*rm)->p->llink=1;
            }
        free(*rm);
        *rm=NULL;
        return;
    }
    if ((*rm)->llink != 1 && (*rm)->llink != 1) {
        if ((*rm)->p->r == (*rm)) {
            (*rm)->p->r = (*rm)->r;
        }
        else (*rm)->p->l = (*rm)->r;
        connectNode(&t,(*rm)->l);
        free(*rm);
        *rm=NULL;
        return;
    }
}
```

После выполнения этой функции я все равно при обходе дерева могу попасть в этот узел.
Для желающих скомпилить, код я выложил сюда:
http://www.codeshare.io/mmoQg
Для того, что бы попасть в это условие можно выполнить следующую последовательность действий:

```
1
15
1
1
35
1
1
45
1
2
45
```

После этого *tail- указатель на максимальный элемент, должен принять значение NULL после удаления, но по факту там остается 45...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если почитать [документацию](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) на функцию `free()`, можно увидеть такую строчку:

> Notice that this function does not change the value of ptr itself, hence it still points to the same (now invalid) location.

Перевод:

> Заметьте, что эта функция не изменяет значение переданного указателя, он указывает на ту же область памяти, но она больше не может быть использована.

Тот факт, что аллокатор не очистил значение, располагающееся по адресу, на который указывает указатель `tail`, не значит, что он не освободил этот участок памяти. Этот участок возвращается в пул свободной памяти и при последующих вызовах `malloc` он может быть заново выделен. Насколько мне известно, стандарт не гарантирует того, что память, освобождёная при помощи `free()` будет очищена.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119134) объяснено более подробно.

Comment: А я же следом по этому адресу NULL записываю. Т.е значение должно все равно поменяться с 45 на NULL, но оно не меняется...

Comment: Вот [ещё по похожей теме](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/276994).

Comment: Я попробовал перед тем, как сделать free сделать следующее: *rm=NULL; но все равно значение в tail не поменялось... Такое впечатление, что я работаю с копией указателя, а не с реальным указателем...

Comment: Угу. Но объясните мне, почему вы так упорно игнорируете отладчики? Вместо того, чтобы тут часами ждать ответов всё это можно увидеть своими глазами за считанные минуты...